# BulkInsert and BulkDelete in EntityFramework6 without using any library or by using any free library

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I want to perform a bulk insertion in postgresql table using entityframework6 and I am getting data from the frontend as a collection. I want to to use bulkinsert (if there is any) to store it, as the data is almost a million. Is there any inbuilt method to use it or any free library that I an use to perform bulk insert and delete?

Comment: Just use ADO.NET directly: (`SqlCommand`, or use `SqlBulkCopy` for `BULK INSERT`), via `DbContext.Database.Connection`.

Answer (score 0):

look if this bulkDelete implementation works for you. https://github.com/Pecs101/ListBulkDelete